# Syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' - Rails 2.1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-2.1, ruby-parser

Getting a syntax error when running rake tasks:

```
 bundle exec rake test:read_message

 ruby -v 
 2.1.0

/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/run.rb:76: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')' (SyntaxError)
..._env, env.server_command, out: File::NULL)

 /usr/lib/ruby-flo/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client/run.rb:76: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
from /usr/lib/ruby-flo/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/lib/spring/client.rb:5
from /usr/lib/ruby-flo/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:48:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby-flo/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.7.1/bin/spring:48
```

Comment: Please, post the code in your rake task

Comment: Is it only rake tasks, or do you get the error when interacting with the code in other ways, such as `irb` or `rails console` or `rails server` or `bundle install`?

Comment: @MichaelGaskill bundle install works fine, getting this issue in running rake tasks.

Comment: post code for your tests and rake task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I disabled spring, was able to run the rake tasks.

**DISABLE_SPRING=1 bundle exec rake test:read_message**

But not sure what is the root cause of issue, it works fine in my local without disabling the spring but not in prod.